# Binary logistic regression with brms

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, binary-data

I've run a binary logistic regression in R, using brms. I have one independent variable (Age) and 3 dependent variables, Y1, Y2, and Y3. These dependent variables are all pass/fail tasks. For each task, I want to model the probability of passing as a function of age. But, I also want to test the hypothesis that those who pass task 2 (Y2 = 1) tend to also pass task 3 (Y3 = 1).

Here is the call & summary:

```r
fit1 <- brm(mvbind(Y1,Y2,Y3) ~ Age + (1|p|Age), data = MyData, family = bernoulli)
add_ic(fit1) <- "loo"
summary(fit1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I'm new to brms, so there are two things I'm a little unsure about. First, how do I interpret the correlation estimates? I understand how to interpret the coefficients under "Population-Level Effects", but how do I interpret those under "Group-Level Effects"? For instance, how do I interpret the estimate of 0.09 for "cor(Y2_Intercept,Y3_Intercept)"? Second, the confidence intervals are very large for each correlation. Is the model suggesting that, in each case, there is no credible correlation? If so, this confuses me, because when I run cor.test, I get the following, which suggests a (statistically significant) moderate correlation:

[image]

Can anyone help me square this all away?

Comment: Interpretation of the correlations will depend on how you have centred age.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So, I just went back and centered age on the mean. The estimates were all virtually the same. Still unsure about what the correlations estimates mean, and how they square away with the cor.test I ran on Y2 and Y3 ...